# GLSL 1.0.0 - Trouble using "Varying" in vertex and fragment shaders

Tags: c++, opengl-es, glsl, shader

I'm developing using OpenGL ES 2.0.0 and GLSL ES 1.0.0.

Currently I'm rendering a square to screen to the screen, and now attempting
to apply a texture.

I'm having trouble using "**varying**" in vertex and fragment shaders,
receiving the error message:

```
- Failed to compile vertex shader - 
0(3) : error C5060: out can't be used with non-varying tex_varying

in vec4 texture_coord ;
in vec4 position ;
out vec2 tex_varying ;
uniform mat4 translate ;
void main ( ) 
{
  gl_Position = translate * position ;
  tex_varying = texture_coord . xy ;
}
```

I've read through the documentation and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code.

Vertex:

```
attribute vec4 position; 
attribute vec4 texture_coord; 
varying vec2 tex_varying; 
uniform mat4 translate; 

void main()
{ 
  gl_Position = translate * position; 
  tex_varying = texture_coord.xy;
}
```

Fragment:

```
varying vec2 tex_varying; 
uniform sampler2D texture; 

void main()
{
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, tex_varying);
}
```

**RESOLVED:**
This is a late reply, but I ended up solving this problem a long time ago - in case anyone else stumbles across the issue. It turns out "tex_varying" is reserved by Nvidia! Simply renaming tex_varying solved the issue.

Cheers.

Comment: You assign a vec4 to a vec2. "tex_varying = texture_coord.xy;"

Comment: Apologies, it's like that in the code, I just copied it up here incorrectly.

Comment: "receiving the error message:" In which shader? What line does it happen on? Can you post the entire error message?

Comment: It happens in the vertex shader. This is the error message:

- Failed to compile vertex shader - 
0(3) : error C5060: out can't be used with non-varying tex_varying

Answer (score 7):

The `in` and `out` keywords as you show them are for GLSL v3 and later.  For v1 (which is what you're trying to use?) you need to replace `in` with `attribute` and `out` with `varying` in the vertex shader.  In the fragment shader, replace `in` with `varying` and you can't use `out` -- you need to output to `gl_FragColor` as you seem to be doing.

So your 2nd/3rd shaders look like you've correctly translated the GLSL v3 code in the first shader to GLSL v1, and look like they should work with ES2/GLSL v1

Comment: The first post is the error message I'm receiving, not the shaders I'm using. The second and third shaders are the ones I'm using, with "varying." 

This is the version I am using.

OpenGL ES 2.0.0
OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.0 Desktop; Shading Language Vendor(NVIDIA Corporation) Version(3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler) Renderer(GeForce 9600 GT/PCI/SSE2)

Comment: It looks like the first block has both an error message and a v3 vertex shader that is generating that error.  The second block has the same shader translated to GLSL v1, which should work.  Or perhaps I'm not understanding what you've posted above.  The other thing that is unclear is where the line `- Failed to compile vertex shader -` is coming from

Comment: Also, that vendor string looks like its desktop GL v3.30, and not GL/ES at all.

Comment: - Failed to compile vertex shader - is me, an output used to see where I've went wrong. Again, the first block is the error message I receive. I'm unsure why it's converted it to v3. Is there some way to make sure I'm using the right version of GLSL?